# How to run migrations from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, migration

I have a gem installed in my rails app, and it has some migrations in

```
/db/migrate
```

how can I run them?

I've tried running

```
 bundle exec rails g gem-name:install
```

but I get an error saying could not find generator gem-name:install.

I've run up against this problem with 3 different Gems this morning. What am I missing?

Comment: You could try rails -T to see available tasks. Usually migrations are copied by an installer to main app migrations and then you execute migrations rails db:migrate

Comment: thanks for this, thats handy to know

Answer (score 8):

Old question, so sorry for the bump, but you were actually pretty dang close.

the correct command would be `rails gem_name:install:migrations`